# Using column generated by listagg in a where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have 3 tables in an oracle database. They look like this:

```
Table User:

username|forename|surname
a          a       a
b          b       b
c          c       c


Table Right:

username|organisationname|right
a           x              user
a           x              admin
a           x              owner
a           y              user
a           y              admin
a           z              owner
b           x              user
c           y              user
c           y              admin
c           z              user

Table Organisation:

organisationname|number
x                 12
y                 14
z                 42
```

The table `Right` has two foreign_keys: `username` points to the column with the same name in the table `user` and `organisationname` to the table `Organisation`.

For all `user` that have the right user on `organisation` x, i want to get a list of all `organisations` (except organisation x) where the user has 1 or more rights.

In my example:
a has right user on x, b has right user on x, c has NOT the right user on x.
So I just want to get all organisations (distinct!, no organisation name twice) for user a and b (and not for c!!!).
If one user has no right on another organisation than x (where he must have the right user), I want that user in the output but with no organisation.

The expected output is:

```
user|organisations
a    y; z
b
```

I hope you understand what i mean.
My query so far is the following:

```
select username, 
/* listagg put all the organisationnames of one user in one column separated by ;  
   then the organsation x gets removed from the result*/
regexp_replace (listagg (organisationname, '; ') 
       within group (order by organisationname), '(^x;?)|( ?x;)|(; x$) ', '') as "organisations"
from(
    select u2.username as username,
           o.organisationname as organisationname,
           /*I do this to remove duplicate entries in the list of organisations of one user */
           row_number() over (partition by u2.username, o.organisationname order by u2.username) as rn
       from RIGHT r2, ORGANISATION o, USER u2 
       where r2.organisationname = o.organisationname
       and r2.username = u2.username
       and r2.username IN
           (
            select u.username
            from USER u, right r
            where r.username = u.username
            and r.right = 'user'
            )  
     order by u2.username, o.organisationname         
)
where rn = 1
group by username
```

That query works, but now i want to filter on the column organisations. But I am not able to use it in the where clause. When I try to use it, oracle throws the error:
ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? I think oracle has problems because of the analytical function listagg.
I would also be happy about suggestions how to simplify my query. Thanks!

Here is what I tried to use the column organisations in the where clause:

```
select * from ( ***long query shown above***) 
where organisations like '%termToSearch%';
```

Comment: Can you also post, what are you trying currently, which gives you the error

Comment: I put query with the where-clause at the end of my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step by step: user names for user|x, then distinct user|organisation except x, then aggregation per username:

```
select
  username,
  listagg(organisationname, '; ') within group (order by organisationname) as organisations
from
(
  select distinct username, organisationname
  from right
  where username in 
  (
    select username 
    from right 
    where organisationname = 'x' and right = 'user'
  )
  and organisationname <> 'x'
)
group by username;
```

(Unfortunately `LISTAGG` doesn't accept a `DISTINCT` keyword, so we need two steps instead of one to build a list of distinct organisations.)

**UPDATE:** To get users without any other organisation, too, we'd remove the condition `and organisationname <> 'x'` and add a case construct to `LISTAGG`:

```
select
  username,
  listagg(case when organisationname <> 'x' then organisationname end, '; ')
    within group (order by organisationname) as organisations
from
(
  select distinct username, organisationname
  from right
  where username in 
  (
    select username 
    from right 
    where organisationname = 'x' and right = 'user'
  )
)
group by username;
```

Comment: Thanks Thorsten. Your query looks much simpler than my query (and i can use the organisation in the where clause). But I think your query doesn't give me the correct result. In my example I have user b who has the right user on organisation x but no right on other organisations. I want to have this user in my output (without any organisation). With your query this user is not in the output because you just look for rights that are not on organisation x.

Answer (score 1):

Change the part of the code, where you are adding Alias,

Old Code -

```
within group (order by organisationname), '(^x;?)|( ?x;)|(; x$) ', '') as "organisations"
```

new code -

```
 within group (order by organisationname), '(^x;?)|( ?x;)|(; x$) ', '') organisations
```

or

new code -

```
within group (order by organizationname), '(^x;?)|( ?x;)|(; x$) ', '') as "ORGANISATIONS"
```

If you still want to use the old code, you can change the last where condition as -

```
where "organisations" like '%termToSearch%';
```

Reference : [Schema Object Names and Qualifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223)

Comment: Thanks! both of your solutions does work! Can you please explain me why it works when I write "ORGANISATIONS" with capital letters instead of lower case?

Comment: @Markus - Updated Answer, The reference link explains how database objects are named and stored.

Comment: @Markus: With quotes you tell the DBMS you want this case sensitive. Without quotes Oracle stores names internally in uppercase. That's why `organisations = ORGANISATIONS = OrGaNiSaTiOnS = "ORGANISATIONS" <> "organisations"`. (The `as` doesn't make any difference by the way.)

Comment: `AS` just makes is easier to read sometimes, its purely a personal preference. @ThorstenKettner is right, it doesn't make any difference at all.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Learned a lot of new things today about SQL (e.g. used listagg for the first time)! I upvoted both of your answers!